# iPhone recorded video is not playing on Android

Tags: video

I uploaded one video from iphone and then playing in android device but it is giving can not play error. Audio encoding is AAC, video encoding H.264 and MPEG_4 format while recording video in iphone.

Why is the iPhone recorded video is not playing on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue now. Actually **IPhone** video was in **.mov** format . As **android** does not support **.mov** so i was getting **can not play** issue. **IPhone** video was in .mp4 in file name only but originally it was in .mov format.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that Android device doesn't support AAC for some reason. You can convert it to another audio format preferably MP3. Try downloading this video converter to your computer: http://www.mirovideoconverter.com    Then, put it back onto the device. If you can't get into your Android device, you will need to download a driver from the company who makes the phone or there are other ways you can transfer that file to your Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

H.264 can be encoded with different profiles and levels. These options guarantee a max. datarate and other important things, to enable encoding for special devices with limited ressources.

In general all devices should be able to decode the Baseline Profile. But it is possible that your video is encoded with a profile which is not readable from your android device.

Cheers,
Matthias